# Why are my Vue instance's properties and methods not available in the template?

Tags: vue.js

- I set up a Vue.js CLI project.
- On a page, I want to define a variable in `data()` and then use it in my template.
- Why does the following code tell me:

> Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
        <p> You can go back to
            <router-link to="/">home</router-link>.</p>
        <p>[{{message}}]</p>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
    name: "Page2",
    data() {
        return {
            message: "here it is"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

And this code:

```
            <button class="btn" @click="test()">the test</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
    name: "Page2",
    data() {
        return {
            message: "here it is"
        }
    },
    methods: {
        test() {
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
}
```

Tells me similarly:

> Property or method "test" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option.

**What else do I need to do to make these variables and methods available in my template on the page?**

This structure of code has worked in other Vue.js CLI projects so it much be something not set right in the project in the environment somewhere.

For instance, this code works in another project:

```
<template>
  <div class="start alert alert-success" role="alert">
    {{ msg }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'start',
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Please choose an option.'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And it works on the `Home` page but not on `Page1` or `Page2`. My `index.js` page looks like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/components/Home";
import Page1 from "@/components/Page1";
import Page2 from "@/components/Page2";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/page1",
      name: "Page1",
      component: Page1
    },
    {
      path: "/page2",
      name: "Page2",
      component: Page2
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Are you sure those warnings are for those components? You don't try to use `message` or `test` in another component where you haven't defined them? That gets me sometimes

Comment: No, this is a very simple project I just started. As the code shows above, I define the `template` section, then below it the `export default` section. The strange thing is another page in another project with the same structure works. Do I have to set some kind of config to get the template and the export default section to know of each other?

Comment: Strange, it works on the Hello.vue page fine, but not on the other pages.

Comment: Do I need to change anything in my `/src/router/index.js` file? (posted above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `<script>` tags around the javascript for your Page1 and Page2 components.

Otherwise, it seems like `vue-loader` just ignores that script and doesn't give you a relevant warning  (just that the data being referenced in your template is missing).

Comment: That was it, I completely didn't see it. Odd it didn't give me another error or display the code on the screen. In any case, thanks.