# vue plugin warning: Property or method is not defined but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a vue plugin but I'm getting the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "count" is not defined on the instance but 
referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the 
data option.
```

I would like to create a single file component which I can import and use but I keep getting this error once I add {{count}} to the template.

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Counter from '/components/counter'


Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(Counter)
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  }
})

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  store:store,
  components: { App, Counter }
})
```

counter/index.js

```
import Counter from './Counter'

const install = function(Vue, opts){
  Vue.component('counter',Counter)
}

export default { install }
```

counter/counter.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
  div {{ count }}
</template>

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      count : 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    count () {
      return this.$store.state.count
    }
  }
}
```

Update : I added the  tag, but my $store is not defined and I'm getting the error:

`vue.esm.js?0de7:476 [Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefine`d"

How can I access the vuex Store from this component? From the vuex doc:

```
By providing the store option to the root instance, the store will be 
injected into all child components of the root and will be available on them 
as this.$store.
```

Comment: You need `<script>` tags around your script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One a Vue.js CLI page, why are variables and methods not available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347155/one-a-vue-js-cli-page-why-are-variables-and-methods-not-available)

Comment: thanks, totally missed that - my store doesn't get passed to the component tough, I can only access it through this.$parent.$store and not with this.$store as in the vuex docs.

Comment: That's a separate question, but I think it's because of the line `Vue.use(Counter)`. That's not how you register a component and you are already registering it on the root instance (`components: { App, Counter }`).